# How to intercept org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault

Tags: java, spring, cxfrs

In my `beans.xml` I have

```
   <jaxrs:server 
   ...
   <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="anonymousService"/>
        <ref bean="accountService"/>
        <ref bean="registerService"/>
        <ref bean="logService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
   ...
   </jaxrs:server>
```

And I found, when some user break his connection from any device, even through Postman I get the exception like

```
Interceptor for {http://application.services/}AnonymousServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
```

If I comment  `<ref bean="anonymousService"/>` exception will be like

```
Interceptor for {http://application.services/}AccountServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
```

and etc.

1) Why does it happen even client call not method from those classes

2) How can I intercept that exception?